# Python Matrix - Limiting Matrix to top 20

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Matrix that counts the number of links between two sets of disciplines that I did through this code from a DF that I created:

```
new_df = df[['GrantRefNumber','Subject']]

a = ['Psychology','Education','Social policy','Sociology','Pol. sci. & internat. studies','Development studies','Social anthropology','Area Studies','Science and Technology Studies','Law & legal studies','Economics','Management & business studies','Human Geography','Environmental planning','Demography','Social work','Tools, technologies & methods','Linguistics','History']
final_df = new_df[new_df['Subject'].isin(a)]

ctrs = {location: Counter(gp.GrantRefNumber) for location, gp in final_df.groupby('Subject')}

ctrs = list(ctrs.items())
overlaps = [(loc1, loc2, sum(min(ctr1[k], ctr2[k]) for k in ctr1))
    for i, (loc1, ctr1) in enumerate(ctrs, start=1)
    for (loc2, ctr2) in ctrs[i:] if loc1 != loc2]
overlaps += [(l2, l1, c) for l1, l2, c in overlaps]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(overlaps, columns=['Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Count'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['Loc1', 'Loc2'])
df2 = df2.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

The Matrix looks like this (It is quite big so took a partial picture:

[image]

I turn the Matrix into a Chord Diagram later on in the code, but wanted a way to filter (or move into a new DF) the data to only show the top 20 (or any number so I can change it with a variable later on) highest numbers in the Matrix, and then put 0 for everything else.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5
1  5  8  3  3
2  4  9  5  6
3  5  4  7  9
4  5  2  1  2
5  4  3  0  4
```

You can create top unique values first and then [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for condition:

```
a = np.sort(np.unique(df.values.ravel()))[-3:]
print (a)
[7 8 9]


df = df.where(df.isin(a), 0)
print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  0  7  0  0
1  0  8  0  0
2  0  9  0  0
3  0  0  7  9
4  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Hey Jezrael, I get the following error? TypeError: nlargest() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given) ... for this code (b = df2.stack().drop_duplicates().nlargest(20).tolist())

Comment: Perfect. Works just the way I want it to. Thank you again :)

Comment: Not sure if you could guess from this, but I am having a problem now with it having divide errors further along in my Chord Diagram with it showing 'nans' in my array where it used to have zeros. Dont worry if you dont know off the top of your head, but thought I would ask before I start my google search! :)..    def map_data(data_matrix, row_value, ideogram_length):
    mapped=np.zeros(data_matrix.shape)
    for j  in range(L):
        mapped[:, j]=ideogram_length*data_matrix[:,j]/row_value
    return mapped

Comment: Dont worry, it is because some of the columns now contain only zeros :)... thank you again

Answer (score 1):

```
df.sort_values(by='AreaStudies',ascending=False).head(20)
```

Comment: Hey Chris, it was probably my mistake from taking a picture of the DF, but I have no column called 'Area Studies' when I try to run your code. I get 'KeyError: 'Area Studies'....  I have tried 'Loc2' etc, but still no luck.

Comment: just replace it with any of your columns name by which you want to do the sorting

Comment: I tried it with several of them i.e. 'Economics' etc, but still producing the same problem. Not sure if is the way I have built the Matrix.

Comment: it seems that you assign `['Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Count']` to be your columns, maybe you can verify by checking `df.columns` and see which columns you have. For a covariance matrix/ frame with equal columns/row, you only need the upper/lower half actually.

Comment: I get the following result from df2.columns: MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Count'], [u'Area Studies', u'Demography', u'Development studies', u'Economics', u'Education', u'Environmental planning', u'History', u'Human Geography', u'Law & legal studies', u'Linguistics', u'Management & business studies', u'Pol. sci. & internat. studies', u'Psychology', u'Science and Technology Studies', u'Social anthropology', u'Social policy', u'Social work', u'Sociology', u'Tools, technologies & methods']]

Comment: I have managed to get it to work though through Jezraels response. Ill still upvote your response though as I am sure it is just my data! :)